# Skew primitive elements of the Taft Hopf algebra

Tags: hopf-algebras

Is there any reference where I can find the skew primitive elements of the Taft Hopf algebra? The Taft algebra is defined here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taft_Hopf_algebra

By a skew primitive element we mean some x of the Hopf algebra such that:
Δ(x) = x ⊗ c + d ⊗ x, where c and d are group like elements.

Thx